# Geany default preferences

Tags: command-line, python, python3, geany

I am trying to get Geany working with Python 3.5 and have made several changes in the Preferences menu. For instance, I changed the Preferences>Tools>Terminal setting to `xterm -e "/bin/sh %c"` following [the Geany manual](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#tools-preferences).

Is there a way to return back to default configuration on Geany ?

Comment: Can you please go into detail: "Can it run Python on something else than a terminal, or print the terminal output somewhere else? " Also only one clear question per question.

Comment: Alright, I will ask an other question for the terminal output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is conf files in **~/.config/geany/** like **keybindings.conf**

1. You may backup and restore these files
2. You may backup and restore geany folder
3. If you dont care your previous configurations simply delete these
   conf files or geany folder

Answer (score 0):

The return to default configurations, just delete ~/.config/geany when Geany is not running. This will reset everything you have done inside your profile. There is no feature which just resets one or two values, but you could edit ~/.config/geany/geany.conf with another editor and change some settings while Geany is not running. But attention: This might cause Geany to not start after.